# how to input values in textboxs and passing it as parameters in function to give a return result

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class named `class 1` with a function as u see below  and a `form1` like in the photo [form1 design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quh9z.png)
I want to know how to put values in textboxes and send those values to this function in this class to give a result which I want to appear in the last textbox of result in the `form1`

```
public class class1
{
    public double func(string A, double b, double c, double d, double e)
    {  

        if (A == "c")
        {
            res= b-c/d-e;
        }
        else if (A == "p")
        {
            res = b+c/d+e;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate and display result on 'Submit' button click?

Comment: [TextBox.Text Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create an event for your button. If you're using WinForms, simply double-click your button and a new Click event will automatically be created for you.

Paste the following code inside and change it according to your variables.

```
string a = TextBox_A.Text;
int b = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_B.Text);
int c = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_C.Text);
int d = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_D.Text);
int e = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_E.Text);  
YourTextBox.Text = func(a,b,c,d,e).ToString();
```

Eventually it should look like this:

```
private void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    string a = TextBox_A.Text;
    int b = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_B.Text);
    int c = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_C.Text);
    int d = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_D.Text);
    int e = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_E.Text);
    YourTextBox.Text = func(a,b,c,d,e).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an **onClick** event method to the result button's onClick eventHandler:

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (A== "c")
       res= b-c/d-e;            
    else if (A== "p")         
       res= b+c/d+e;
    textBox_result.Text = res;
)
```

Where **textBox_result** is the name of the textbox you want to present the result in.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to access the text values from another class? In general you should not access textboxes from an outside class, as you also see that a textbox is a protected field an d thus inaccessible from an outside class. I recommend you to do this from your Form1 class, like so (create a click event on your SubmitButton):

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double res = 0;

    string a = TextBoxA.Text;
    double b = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxB.Text);
    double c = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxC.Text);
    double d = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxD.Text);
    double e = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxE.Text);

    // Use .equals to compare strings!
    if (a.Equals("c"))
    {
        // Are you sure this shouldn't be (b-c)/(d-e)?
        res= b-c/d-e;
    }
    else if (a.Equals("p"))
    {
        // Are you sure this shouldn't be (b+c)/(d+e)?
        res= b+c/d+e;
    }
    TextboxResult.Text = res.ToString();
}

private double GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(string value)
{  
    // Ideally you should check whether the parsing has succeeded!  
    double.TryParse(value, out double doubleValue);
    return doubleValue;
}
```

If you really want to change the value from another class, you should add a public function to Form1 that gets and sets the value of textBox. What you could do is just call your class, so you work from Form1 to set your TextBoxes and from Class to calculate your result.

In form1:

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double res = 0;

    string a = TextBoxA.Text;
    double b = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxB.Text);
    double c = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxC.Text);
    double d = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxD.Text);
    double e = GetTextBoxValueAsDouble(TextBoxE.Text);

    double res = class1.Func(a, b, c, d, e);

    TextboxResult.Text = res.ToString();
}
```

In class1:

```
public double Func( string a, double b, double c, double d, double e)
{ 
    // Use .equals to compare strings!
    if (a.Equals("c"))
    {
        // Are you sure this shouldn't be (b-c)/(d-e)?
        res= b-c/d-e;
    }
    else if (a.Equals("p"))
    {
        // Are you sure this shouldn't be (b+c)/(d+e)?
        res= b+c/d+e;
    }
    return res;
}
```